# Will adding multiple attributes in model leads to performance issues using Spring MVC?

Tags: java, performance, spring-mvc, web-applications

Nearly 50 attributes are set to Model object, which includes lists, enums, strings

```
model.addAttribute("casetype", Casetype.values());
model.addAttribute("caseStatus", CaseStatus.values());
```

This is common code which execute for every controller but for all controller we need only 4 - 5 attrbutes and all other 45 attribute are of no use.

Will there be any performance benefit if we remove these 45 attributes, or let it remain as it is for all controllers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The model is basically a `HashMap<String, Object>`. Every value you put into your Model will trigger a put operation on the `HashMap`. Put/Get operations on a `HashMap` are *usually* `O(1)`. Putting all these values into the model does however take some computation power and these values will stay in memory while rendering your view and have to be garbage collected at some point.

TLDR: Putting all those variables into your model does affect performance but it really depends on how large your application is and how often your endpoints are triggered. If you need maximum performance you should strip off any redudant items from your model object, if it's just some users then you can probably leave it as is.

Comment: Say 200 - 500 Users in parallel